# trunc(add_months(sysdate,3),'Q')-1 equivalent expression in Postgres

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, date, datetime

can anybody convert this oracle expression `trunc(add_months(sysdate,3),'Q')-1)`  to postgresql?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this expression gives you the last day of the current quarter (provided that you remove the last closing parenthese, which otherwise is a syntax error).

In postgres, you could phrase this as:

```
date_trunc('quarter', current_date)  + interval '3 months' - interval '1 day'
```

This generates a `timestamp` value, that you can cast if you want a `date` (this distinction does not exist in Oracle, where a `date` stores the time component as well).

Answer (score 0):

The Postgres equivalent of your Oracle calculation can be seen below.

```
select date_trunc('quarter', current_date + interval '3 month') - interval '1 day'
```